# Function setonkeypress is not working with datepicker

Tags: javafx, keypress

In JavaFX the setOnKeyPressed event is not hitting in datepicker field through the program whereas for other fields its working properly.

It's not hitting,

```
dateOfBirth.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>(){
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
                if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.TAB) {
                    event.consume();
                    nationality.requestFocus();
                }
            }
});
```

I wanna get to know the reason and solution.

Comment: What actually happens?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34690319/2396250 It worked form me..!!